# Able to instantiate an object but not access its functions - 'Symbol(s) not found' error

Tags: c++, circular-buffer, undefined-symbol

I'm using the 'TPCircularBuffer' class for creating a circular buffer object, from [this website](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-simple-fast-circular-buffer-implementation-for-audio-processing/).
This is my current code:

```
 TPCircularBufferRecord bufferRecord;                   //1
 TPCircularBufferInit(&bufferRecord, kBufferLength);    //2
```

Line 1 works fine, so that means the linker has found the .cpp and .h files for the class. However, line 2 doesn't compile, with the error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "TPCircularBufferInit(TPCircularBufferRecord*, int)", referenced from:
      StereoEffect3::StereoEffect3(ComponentInstanceRecord*)in StereoEffect3-1DB483EC8D75827.o
      StereoEffect3::StereoEffect3(ComponentInstanceRecord*)in StereoEffect3-1DB483EC8D75827.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't think it's a problem with the original source code, but I'll include it here anyway:
[TPCircularBuffer.c](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer/blob/master/TPCircularBuffer.c)

[TPCircularBuffer.h](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer/blob/master/TPCircularBuffer.h)

Does anyone know why the linker/compiler can't find the function TPCircularBufferInit?
The TPCircularBufferInit function is as follows:

```
 inline void TPCircularBufferInit(TPCircularBufferRecord *record, int length) {
     record->head = record->tail = record->fillCount = 0;
     record->length = length;
 }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm passing the correct type of arguments into it...

Comment: it's worth noting that the original code is for C, but i'm using it in c++. i just renamed the .c file to .cpp, and changed some of the pointers from void to float, as it didn't seem to like pointer arithmetic with void pointers...

Comment: Try removing the `inline` from the source file. Inlined functions really only belong in header files.

Comment: @JimmyB : I'd **strongly** recommend using [`Boost.CircularBuffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/circular_buffer/index.html) instead of shoehorning in this poor C code.

Comment: thanks ildjarn, I'll check the boost library out now!

Comment: @ildjarn
i'd love to use boost, but i can't get it to install...

Comment: @JimmyB : Boost.CircularBuffer is header-only, there's nothing to "install" -- you just need the header files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing and matching C and C++ code.

The TPCircularBuffer.h isn't C++ safe, so when you include it in your C++ source, it'll get treated as C++. That'll fail, in this case only at link time. The linker will look for C++ name mangeled symbols for the cicrular buffer functions, but TPCircularBuffer.c is compiled as C code.

Just do this where you include the TPCircularBuffer.h header:

```
extern "C" {
#include "TPCircularBuffer.h"
};
```

Alternativly, this code should be ok when compiled as C++ too, so just rename the TPCircularBuffer.c file to TPCircularBuffer.cpp

Comment: that worked great - i included that code and renamed the source file back to TPCircularBuffer.c (from .cpp) and it builds fine. thank you!